# How to use variable from javascript in inline css?

Tags: javascript, css, variables

Trying to call the "color" variable for use in the inline css. I'll replace the "red" output with a function but I need to know how to do this first. Thanks

Code:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var color = "red"
        </script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>New Tab</title>
        <style>
            .fit {
                max-height: 99vh;
                max-width: 99%;             
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body style="color: black" scrolling="no">
            <div class="card text-white" >
                <div style= "text-align: center;">
                    <div id= "someInput" style= "background-color: color;">
                        <img class= "fit";  id="img1" id="i" src="" style= ""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                
    <script src="/randomthing.js"></script>
    <script src="/randomthing2.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/background.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Tried to look at other forums but didn't find any solution

Comment: I don't think is possible with inlined css; you need javascript to access the element to change its style. But, if you really need the variable on "top" of your code, you can try with php.

Comment: Why go through this effort? Remove the inline CSS, add a class to the element, and then use `className` or `classList` in the JS to update its colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) which can be used almost anywhere<sup>1</sup> in your css. To define a CSS variable, you need to use the `--` prefix:

```css
--my-variable: red;
```

You can, then, use this variable in your css, by using the function `var`

```css
color: var(--my-variable);
```

You could use the [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) function, on the `style` property of your element, to define the value for the variable you want

```js
const color = 'red';

const input = document.getElementById('someInput');

input.style.setProperty('--my-variable', color);
```

```html
<div class="card text-white" >
    <div style= "text-align: center;">
        <div id= "someInput" style= "background-color: var(--my-variable);">
            <img class= "fit";  id="img1" id="i" src="" style= ""/>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

<sup>1</sup> Note, the scope of the css variable is determined by where it is declared in the hierarchy. In the previous exemple, since both the variable and the style that uses it are defined on the element directly, they are accessible. You could not use this variable on another element. See Css variable scoping for more information on the subject.

Comment: css variable can be used anywhere if you declare it in `:root` scope.

Comment: So I got the CSS variable to work but i still can't figure out how to set it equal to the js variable. The input.style.setProperty isn't working

Comment: It seams to be working on the example i gave you, are you using it like i am ?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to use a variable from javascript in css, but one way that i think is the most efficient is by define a [css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), so you can reuse that css variable later on in the project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var color = "red";
    
    //  add thie line to define a css variable from javascript called "--color"
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', color);
    
  </script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>New Tab</title>
  <style>
    /*  to define a css variable in css */
    :root{
      --my-test-variable: 123px /*  this is like a global css variable */
    }

    .fit {
      max-height: 99vh;
      max-width: 99%;
    }
    
    /*  to use a css variable in css*/
    .test-using-css-variable{
      width: var(--my-test-variable); /*  call var() function to use the variable */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="color: black" scrolling="no">
  <div class="card text-white">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div id="someInput" style="background-color: var(--color);"> <!--  to use a css variable, you need to call var() function -->
        <img class="fit" ; id="img1" id="i" src="" style="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/randomthing.js"></script>
    <script src="/randomthing2.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```